# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I have tried many solutions found here like adding this to my .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But it didn't work. Any other solutions? Thanks!

Down below i added my full csproj file, hope it helps to solve my problem.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-TestDotNet-f4c2182a-efeb-4bba-a5ae-a69442b94972</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Are you using the Package Manager or Command Line?  'dotnet ef' commands ONLY work from CLI ... dotnet restore, build etc will work from PM Console.

Also, do you have the corresponding PackageReference?

Comment: Command Line. Yes i have them

Comment: Can you put your full .csproj up?  It might help.

Comment: I added my full file in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing the 32-bit version of the .NET core SDK